# NAS password not saved in Gnome / CentOS 7

Tags: centos, gnome, password, gnome3, gnome-keyring

I am setting up a new system that is running CentOS 7 and Gnome 3.28.2. I've used CentOS from the command line before but this is my first time using Gnome.

I have found that Gnome does not seem to remember the password for my Network-Attached Storage. When I connect to my NAS, Gnome asks me for the user name and password. I check the box to save the credentials, but Gnome doesn't actually remember them and asks me again the next time I boot the system and connect to the NAS.

I have verified that `gnome-keyring` and `seahorse` are installed.

Why else might Gnome be forgetting the credentials? Is there something else I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. Originally I was reconnecting to the NAS by going to Files > Other Locations > Connect to Server. This always asks for my credentials, even if I check the box to remember them. I got around this by bookmarking the shared folder on the NAS. If I click on the bookmark in Files, it connects and opens the folder immediately without asking for my credentials.